# .exe file stops and eventually starts after building in QtCreator?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I made an application using Qt in QtCreator. Recently, I noticed there's a persistent yet inconsistent occurrence of a problem. When I build it, whether it is release or debug mode, the program gives an error as shown in the following images

[image]

[image]

Then without even without any response from me, after a few seconds, the dialog closes and program eventually starts. This occurrence doesn't always happen, sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't.

I'm not sure if these issues are relevant, but I also notice the following issues in the `Application Output` window of Qt Creator:

```
Exception at 0x756a1d4d, code: 0xe06d7363: C++ exception, flags=0x1 (execution cannot be continued) (first chance) in SPVC32Loader

Exception at 0x756a1d4d, code: 0xe06d7363: C++ exception, flags=0x1 (execution cannot be continued) (first chance) in SPVC32Loader
```

Do you have any idea why I'm having this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Have you even *tried* debugging the program?

Comment: Of course I did. I can't find any problem, otherwise I wouldn't ask.

Comment: I realize now what happened. It was mainly because of the `SPVC32Loader.dll` avast was cause that error message. Once I cleaned it, it's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPVC32Loader appears to be a browser hijacker. I would suggest you verify if you have this dll in your system and then removing it. [Here](http://deletemalware.blogspot.gr/2014/01/what-is-spvc32loaderdll-and-how-to.html) is a relevant link.